# PHP session not working with multiple WordPress pages

Tags: php, wordpress, session

Please help. I have three PHP pages and I have pasted the following code snippets on each using the “Woody snippets.”  plugin. These sessions sometimes communicate within pages based on which page I published last. For example, if I publish `page 1` last, I can see the session['rate'] values showing up on `page 2` and `page 3`. But if I publish `page 3` last and went into `page 1` to populate session[‘rate’] and come back to `page 3` again, `page 3` will not have this value.

**Page 1 code**

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
$_SESSION['rate'] = 50;
echo "<br>".$_SESSION['rate']."<br>" ;
?>
```

**Page 2 code**

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "<br>".$_SESSION['rate']."<br>";
$_SESSION['rate'] = 10; //This change wont effect on page 1 if I re-visit it. 
?>
```

**Page 3 code**

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "<br>".$_SESSION['rate']."<br>";
?>
```

I have installed the “[Native PHP Sessions for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-native-php-sessions/)” plugin as well, which claims there is an issue with PHP sessions working properly with WordPress. But still no help. You can copy this code and past it into 3 different WordPress pages and you will still see the issue. (session[‘rate’] value is base on which page I publish last. I tried putting  `session_start();` on the `header.php` file on the appropriate theme file as well. Still no luck). Placing the following code on the `function.php` file doesn't help either:

```
function ses_init() {
   if (!session_id())
   session_start();
}
add_action('init','ses_init');
```

Later on, I want a user to stay logged in using sessions. But if sessions are no longer working properly with WordPress, this will not be feasible.

Comment: If you are following the value of cookie `PHPSESSID`, did you see something wrong (eg: value changed or cookie removed)?

Comment: try lowering the priority to 1 in functions.php for `add_action('init','ses_init', 1);`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried lowering the priority but still have the same issue. All 3 pages show having the same session ID. My hosting provider is `hostinger`. When I copy this code and paste it on another hosting provider that uses WordPress, this code works fine. I have tried removing WordPress and reinstalling back at `hostinger`. Both websites I have under this `hostinger` hosting service behave the same way.

Comment: Some hosting providers won't support sessions. Contact their support or try cookies instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is not, I think, a session issue. I had something very similar happen to me in a different kind of WP application I had to work with.

The basic reason is that WP takes great pains to optimize the connection, traffic, and rendering of pages. But if your three pages are "normal" pages accessed via GET method, then they will publish several metadata (ETag, If-Modified-Since header, etc.) that do not "know" that the content changed.

Without looking at the site I can't be sure whether this is your case, but I can tell you how I fixed *my* problem, which was similar in some ways to yours (I had some information updated in page A, that might have needed to be shown in page B of the same user, and the old version was shown instead).

Usually I would have fixed the caching pragmas or [used a cache-buster](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-exclude-1-page-from-caching/), and maybe you can. My own case was slightly different - I did not describe it completely - and more complicated, so I could not do this.

What I did instead was way more complicated, but it worked perfectly and scaled very well. In your terms, I changed the code to

```
echo '<span id="rate"></span>';
```

and added a Javascript code to make an AJAX call that read the `$_SESSION` value and put it in the span:

```
jQuery.post('/utilities/rate.php').then(reply => {
    jQuery('#rate').text(reply.rate);
});
```

The `rate.php` file retrieved the session,

```
<?php
    // Use readonly session to improve performances and avoid locks
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.0.0') >= 0) {
        session_start([ 'read_and_close' => true ]);
    } else {
        session_start();
        session_write_close(); 
    }
    $ret = [ 'rate' => $_SESSION['rate'] ];
    header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
    print json_encode($ret);
```

and this allowed me (this was another requirement) to update the information periodically (I used window.setTimeout in Javascript) even if the page was not reloaded, or the data changed server side, as soon as it changed.

## update

Just to verify, try whether it's possible to send cache headers from the page -- and if they work.

```
session_start();
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT");
```

## confirmed

It is a cache of some type (from the headers I suspect "X-LiteSpeed Cache").

If I request the a1 page adding "?_=" and a random number to the URL, I get the updated page with the 50 rate value as expected.

It can probably be disabled site-wide, but then the site would become slow. There appear to be some headers that [can be used to disable the cache](https://docs.litespeedtech.com/lscache/devguide/controls/) for specific requests.

Try either

```
header('X-Litespeed-Cache_Control: no-cache');
```

or
header('X-Litespeed-Cache_Control: no-store');

If not even this works, I'm really afraid you'll need to consider the AJAX solution, or an ugly cachebusting.

Comment: Was the website you had issues with while back hosted by Hostinger? When I copy and past this code at another website hosted by a different hosting company, my code works fine. Following are the 3 pages I am testing on with Hostinger: 1) http://premiertechnologyhub.com/index.php/a1/
2) http://premiertechnologyhub.com/index.php/a2/
3) http://premiertechnologyhub.com/index.php/a3/ 
I have tried deleting all my accounts and resetting them. Still, PHP sessions won't work properly with them.

Comment: No, it was an Italian provider. But a different web site, hosted by a different web company, might well have **a different Wordpress configuration** - and that would be the key.

I tried your links, they gave a 404 page, so I looked around on Hostinger blog, since I suspect they use the same optimizations for their own systems than they do for yours. And, indeed, I'm seeing a lot of 304 cache hits and (to me) unusual CloudFlare load balancing headers. I'm pretty sure you're seeing a caching effect here.

Comment: Thank you for looking into that. I had my account deleted at that time to see if it fix the issue. I have reinstalled WordPress. You can check out those 3 sites now. In the update section of your answer, you told me to see if it's possible to send cache headers from the page. Did you want me to put these lines of codes on top of those 3 pages? If so, I have done that and  you can see those 3 pages by going here: 1) premiertechnologyhub.com/index.php/a1 2) premiertechnologyhub.com/index.php/a2 3) premiertechnologyhub.com/index.php/a3

Comment: Okay, the page a1 is *always* sending the same ETag header, from something that calls itself "X-LiteSpeed-Cache".

As a new test, I'd try sending the ETag header with a value of uniqid(), so that each call always returns a different value. If the page still replies with an unchanging ETag, then it's a big problem, and we need to either override the Litespeed cache or use the AJAX solution. If I invoke the a1 page adding a cachebuster (".../a1?_=123456") then it seems to work, but that's *aaaawkward*.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You are a lifesaver. On WordPress, hostinger has installed a "LiteSpeed Cache" App. Deactivating this app didn't solve the issue. By going to the settings of the "LiteSpeed Cache" app and turning off the "Enable Cache" option fixed this issue. Thank you again for your time and all the detailed explanations. Greatly appreciate that.

Comment: @DP Try with the headers if at all possible. Chances are that disabling the cache over the whole Wordpress installation might have a significant performance impact. You don't want that.

Comment: Adding `header('X-Litespeed-Cache_Control: no-cache');` or `header('X-Litespeed-Cache_Control: no-store');` top of those 3 pages didn't solve the issue. If you see the 3 pages now, they have both of those lines of codes on top of each page.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise on printing the session id on each page and make sure its the same, otherwise there is something wrong with your php session configuration, that is restarting the session every time instead of resuming it.

You can print the id using the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo session_id();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. They all have the same session_id. If you create 3 separate WordPress pages with the same code, you will see the issue I am talking about. Thank you for looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

Question: Why are you starting a new session on each page? What if you tried:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
session_start();
$_SESSION['rate'] = 10;
}else{
echo "<br>".$_SESSION['rate']."<br>" ;
}
```

Failing that just write the values to cookie, its much easier